# Nested namespaces in layout xml

Tags: android, xml, google-maps

I want to place MapFragment inside RelativeLayout. The problem is that I have to use some custom attributes like **zOrderOnTop**  that belong to a different namespace.

If I put fragment as root element everything is fine:

```
<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    class="com.mycompany.testproj.CustomMapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_margin="40dp"
    map:zOrderOnTop="true"
    android:background="#00000000"
/>
```

But when trying to put fragment inside RelativeLayout I get an error

> Unexpected namespace prefix "xmlns" found for tag "fragment"

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <fragment
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        class="com.mycompany.testproj.CustomMapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_margin="40dp"
        map:zOrderOnTop="true"
        android:background="#00000000"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem by using inlude:

**map_view.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


<include layout="@layout/map_fragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**map_fragment.xml**

```
<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    class="com.mycompany.testproj.CustomMapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_margin="40dp"
    map:zOrderOnTop="true"
    android:background="#00000000"
/>
```